# PayPal Transaction charges using delayed chained payment

Tags: paypal, transactions, payment

I have to integrate PayPal's delayed chained payment to a US based Peer-to-peer marketplace. I need to know how much is the PayPal's transaction charge in the whole process. 
For Example, if sender makes a transaction of $100 for a product, how much of that will be received by Primary receiver (Platform owner)? Then, suppose Primary receiver further transfers $80 to secondary receiver after retaining his commission, how much the secondary receiver will receive out of $80?
Thanks